# Слетела кодировка с сайта после попытки настройки htacess

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Слетела кодировка с сайта после того, как попытался вручную отключить редиректы в htacess.

Содержание файла было вот таким:

```
AddCharset utf-8 .js
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddEncoding gzip .gz
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Safari
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.css$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.js$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(css|js)?$ $1.$2.gz [QSA,L]

DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f



RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access 7 days"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7 day"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 year"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
```

После удаления строк, отвечающих непосредственно за редирект, с сайта слетела кодировка. Замена htacess на оригинальный не помогает.

В итоге, сайт выглядит примерно вот так:
[image: Сайт со сбитой кодировкой]

Ссылка на сайт: https://mosprom.com/

Comment: А сам файл `htaccess` выполняется? Редиректы работают?

Comment: Нет. Дальше главной страницы на сайте уйти нельзя.

Comment: Значит у Вас просто полностью `.htaccess` слетел.

Comment: Проблема в том, что если я полностью удаляю файл htacess из корневой папки, то сайт вообще становится недоступным.
При добавлении же "оригинального" файла с кодом, сайт работает, однако кодировка сбита и дальше главной страницы пользователя не пускает. 
Выдаёт ошибку: 
Not Found
The requested URL /uslugi/sertifikacija-produkcii/ was not found on this server.

Comment: Не могу утверждать точно, но мне кажется, что в файле `.htaccess` могут быть ошибки, из-за чего он может работать не корректно. В примере именно тот файл, который загружаете, верно?

Comment: Да. Все "слетело" после того, как я внес в него правки, удаляющие строки, отвечающие за редирект.
И даже бекапа исходного файла (который в примере), сайта корректно не работает.